# Selenium RC is not opening new IE window rather throwing javascript error

Tags: javascript, selenium-rc

I am automating my project using selenium RC-Java-Eclipse, though am new to it.
I have 2 tabs in my application, one to enter details and save it, 2nd will open up a new window to do certain task.
I am running my selenium RC code in iexplore.
when selenium is clicking on the 2nd tab, javascript error is displaying, which is supposed to open a new window.

```
selenium.click("link=Link / Unlink");
```

> Javascript error: Webpage error details
>
> User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1;
>   Trident/4.0; InfoPath.2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152;
>   .NET CLR 3.5.30729) Timestamp: Tue, 8 Nov 2011 09:08:43 UTC
>
> Message: Object doesn't support this property or method Line: 383
>   Char: 2 Code: 0 URI: http://172.20.160.136/scripts/common.js

i am in a hurry to make it automated....but its blocking me to load new window... please suggest what to do.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar case where I would click on a button to open a new popup window, do some stuff there, etc. This is how I did,

```
selenium.click("//td[@id='openNew']");

selenium.waitForPopUp("", DEFAULT_TIMEOUT);
String[] windowNames = selenium.getAllWindowNames();
assertEquals(2, windowNames.length);
selenium.selectWindow(windowNames[1]);
```

maybe you are not waiting for the window to open and then not selecting the right window which may have some js links.. and your control is still on the original window that why errors..

Comment: just to add, DEFAULT_TIMEOUT is just a constant I defined in my file to specify a value in milliseconds, and then I am asserting that there would be 2 windows i.e. 1 main window (index 0) and 1 popup (index 1), then I am selecting the window index 1, which is my popup window.

Comment: Thanks Ashley. I just directly used ur code except selenium.click... but SAME RESULT AGAIN- new window is not opening upon clicking on tab! and javascript error in status bar of the main window.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT="40000". DO i need to do any manipulation...plz tell me how can overcome it..

Comment: @user1035170 - are you getting the same error still? I am sure you verified that the application runs fine when accessed directly. Its hard for me to tell without seeing your code. Let's see.. Which window links to common.js? the main one or the popup? If on the main page then maybe you have your link to js file at the page end and you are clicking the link before the page has loaded completely.. if thats the case then you may try putting a waitForPageToLoad before clicking the link. Like I said hard to give a solution without looking at your code.

Comment: I guess common.js links to popup window. bcz from viewPageSource i got this below code which shows that clicking on tab fires javascript function which should load the new popup window.
<li><a rel="#tab_2_contents" id="flightid/16" onclick="javascript: openPopupRights(16,'flight/link/index');" class="tab">Link / Unlink</a></li>.... can we figure out from this clue...otherwise i have to contact to developers regarding the link of common.js...

Comment: yep first thing u need to check is whether the application works on its own like i mentioned in my last comment. Access the same page without selenium i.e the live application. If that doesnt work its somethng the dev team needs to fix. If that works we will proceed our investigation.

Comment: any way I can see the html of the page and your test case

Comment: cant tell much without looking at the code. Its some script related issue. Either common.js is not yet loaded when you click the link or some js call hasnt happened that is used by common.js. Or else there is some javascript that hasn't run yet. I see a rel attribute on your link. Generally rel is used when there is some stuff to happen thru js on that element. Your best bet is to get hold of a developer to help you out. share us your code using jsfiddle maybe..

Comment: Not exactly same as your problem, but you can maybe look for some clues here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/633600/selenium-click-event-seems-not-to-be-always-triggered-results-in-timeout

Comment: thanks Ashley. that link gave me one idea which is 2 times click on the tab. apart from that thr are all tries and no results.. :) i went with 2 times click on the :)monster:) tab.... its again same javascript error...

Comment: seems most likely to be a script load issue. selenium is clicking the link before some scripts have either loaded or finished running. did you try the waiting for page to load before clicking the link. try to give some sleep duration as well... if you cant share the code then get hold of a developer to assist you.

Comment: I am using 'sleep' before clicking the tab... below is the code.

AAPTestSuite.selenium.click("link="+objAAPObjects.flightName);
          AAPTestSuite.selenium.getAllFields();
          Thread.sleep(5000);

if(AAPTestSuite.selenium.isElementPresent("link=Link / Unlink"))
          {
           System.out.println("Link Unlink tab found, now going to click");
           AAPTestSuite.selenium.fireEvent("link=Link / Unlink", "click");
                    }
          else
          {
           System.out.println("Link Unlink tab not found");
           
          }

Comment: i found it modal dialogue window which has javascript activities. Can we not work on modal windows?

Comment: could u plz tell me how we can work on modal windows? does it require more time span before loading modal popup? does it require closing of parent window?

Answer (score 0):

Your application is broken.  `scripts/common.js` is **not** part of Selenium.  Report the error as a bug to the application developers.

Comment: i can log it saying a bug if found while doing manually. But its working fine when manually clicked on tab and getting my desired popup window opened.
This javascript error i am getting when dealing with selenium and trying to load popup winodw through selenium only...
so any luck!

Answer (score 0):

Check if there is any event associated to tab click, like onclick event. If so try to fire that event using selenium.fireevent("identifier","eventname"). Also try clicking on tab using xpath once. There may be some other element with same name.

Comment: yes. I found the below html code from ViewPageSource for that tab.
<li><a rel="#tab_2_contents" id="flightid/16" onclick="javascript: openPopupRights(16,'flight/link/index');" class="tab">Link / Unlink</a></li>... we have onclick event associated to tab click. Let me try with selenium.fireevent("link=Link / Unlink","onClick")..

Comment: I tried with XPath, it dint work out.
I wrote selenium.fireEvent("link=Link / Unlink","onclick") and run selenium. It thrown error at this command and The error message is: Invalid argument.
Did i go wrong anywhere???

Comment: eventname would be click and not onclick.

Comment: Same thing happening again with eventname click i.e javascript error. its really brain eating without any solution :) help!